# Check if a value is present in an (unsorted) array

Tags: iterator, range, d

In D language `in` operator allows to check if a value is present in a sorted random access range.

But if I want to check if a value is present in an unsorted and not random access range, how to do it?

Comment: A sorted range provides operations (binary search in your case) that take advantage of the fact the range is sorted.  To check for a single value in an unsorted range, you can iterate through the range (find).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree with Lupus that `countUntil` does the job, there's a different function that may have less overhead and a more reasonable name: `canFind`:

```
import std.algorithm.searching : canFind;
if (haystack.canFind(needle)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can u expand on why canFind has less overhead?

Comment: Depending on the range type, `countUntil` will need to do some more calculations - increment the result value for each `popFront` in one case, calculating the length difference between two ranges in another, possibly more. Simply put, `canFind` returns less information, so it can calculate less. Note that this doesn't necessarily translate to more efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std.algorithm.searching : countUntil`

```
import std.algorithm.searching : countUntil
if (array.countUntil(lookingFor) != -1) {
    // . . .
}
```

`count Until` is like indexOf in many other languages.

https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#countUntil